# Select default option on null angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this dropdown select is working

```
 <select name="name" [(ngModel)]="name">
 <option value="ACTIVE" [selected]="name.status=='ACTIVE' || name.status==null">Active</option>
 <option value="INACTIVE" [selected]="name.status=='INACTIVE'">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

but i want if `name.status` is null then by default select `ACTIVE`.

This is not working.

Any Solution Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `ngModel` and `selected` aren't supposed to be used together.
In fact the selection selects whatever fits the options value compared to ngModels value.

Hence the right way would be:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="name.status">
  <option value="ACTIVE">Active</option>
  <option value="INACTIVE">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

This snippet only doesn't handle the case, that default is null. I recommend to patch the field on init.

Such a patch could look like:

```
name: NameType;
@Input()
set rawName(value: NameType) {
  this.name = {
    ...value,
    status: value.status || 'ACTIVE';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but if null or blank in `name.status` first option is not selected

Comment: Extended my answer

Comment: this checkbox is inside for loop and is dynamic will the above solution work, name is inside array of object

Comment: You could wrap the select into a component. `<app-nameselection *ngFor="name of names" [rawName]="name"></app-nameselection>`

Comment: can you please suggest any other solution without creating different component

Answer (score 0):

Default select will work on behalf of your NgModule variable value .So you  have to mange inside .ts . if null value then assign active to your name.status

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="name" [ngModel]="name.status || 'ACTIVE'" (ngModelChange)="name.status=$event">
  <option value="ACTIVE">Active</option>
  <option value="INACTIVE">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

However, this will not change the value of name.status to 'ACTIVE' to do that you have to code it from .ts